# Streamlit crashes while importing torch

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, torch, streamlit

Im trying to load my model and make an app using streamlit but the app crashes while importing torch. Does anyone know the reason?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you add it to your requirements file as "torch" (not pytorch -- I've had my app crash when I've tried importing it as pytorch or listing it as pytorch in my requirements file), it should work. If your app is using a large amount of resources, that could be the cause of the crash. Here's a [repo](https://github.com/carolinedlu/st-pytorch)  for a Streamlit app that imports torch that I've been able to deploy succesfully.